# get position in a api swift Codable and Model data

Tags: ios, swift, codable

i am getting data from an api like this

```
[
  {
    "internData": {
      "id": "abc123",
      "name": "Doctor"
    },
    "author": "Will smith",
    "description": "Is an actor",
    "url": "https://www",
  },
  {
    "internData": {
      "id": "qwe900",
      "name": "Constructor"
    },
    "author": "Edd Bett",
    "description": "Is an Constructor",
    "url": "https://www3",
  }
]
```

I have my model like this

```
struct PersonData: Codable {
    let author: String?
    let description: String?
    let url: String?
}
```

But I dont know how to define the "internData", I tried with another Model "InterData" and define id and name like the PersonData, but i get an error, i tried also with [String:Any] but i get an error for the Codable protocol

I am using

```
let resP = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .init()) as? [String: AnyObject]
            print("resP", )
```

in my script of Service/Network

Thanks if somebody knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `[String:Any]` type in case of `Codable`. you need to create an another model of `InternData`, which is used by `PersonData`.

Code:

JSON Data :

```
let jsonData =
"""
[
{
"internData": {
"id": "abc123",
"name": "Doctor"
},
"author": "Will smith",
"description": "Is an actor",
"url": "https://www",
},
{
"internData": {
"id": "qwe900",
"name": "Constructor"
},
"author": "Edd Bett",
"description": "Is an Constructor",
"url": "https://www3",
}
]
"""
```

// Models

```
struct PersonData: Codable {
    let author: String?
    let description: String?
    let url: String?
    let internData : InternData?
}

// New model 

struct InternData : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
}
```

// Parsing

```
do {
    let parseRes = try JSONDecoder().decode([PersonData].self, from: Data(jsonData.utf8))
    print(parseRes)
}
catch {
     print(error)
}
```

Comment: Please, do not suggest to print `localizedDescription`, in a Decoding context, print **always** the `error` instance.  `localizedDescription`shows a meaningless generic error message.

Comment: what woulb be jsonData?

Comment: you can use your object(Data) which is `data`.

Comment: i get this error
err valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "interData", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))